# convert json encoded array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

i was trying to get the location of the particular device .i am getting the location but can't merge with javascript .

My AJAX is returning JSOn Encoded Array Like

```
[{"title":"Thudi","lat":"11.0812178","lng":"76.94155735"}]
```

in Java script variable i have to assign this value like -

```
var markers = [{"title":"NGGO ","lat":"11.0888676","lng":"76.94175196"}];
```

i tried many methods to convert json array to js variable, array but i am not getting the exact answer

Comment: What's one of the methods you tried?

Comment: JSON.parse(myArray) ?

Comment: i tried json.stringify , parse..., but i am getting with back slashes. not getting exact answer

Comment: `JSON.parse` will definitely, absolutely work for your example. What error are you getting?

Comment: markers[0] is already an object why would you parse it?

Comment: JSON.parse("[{"title":"NGGO ","lat":"11.0888676","lng":"76.94175196"}]"); should work ideally.

Comment: Backslashes would happen if you used stringify on an (non-parsed) JSON string. On the other hand, AJAX might have parsed it for you already. Have you tried assigning the returned array to the marker? Like function(e){var markers = e}

Comment: `My AJAX is returning JSOn Encoded Array` **WRONG** ... it is returning a javascript array with one object in it. You can just assign this value to your variable as is without any alterations. **OR** your question is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you describe you question more clear?
I guess your question is convert returning JSON stirng to JS Object.

```
JSON.parse(/*returnining json string*/)
```